# Add State to "Push" React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to add state to my "push" request with React Router 4.

I see many examples but when I try to do it my component where I want to check the "state" is undefined.

my understanding this is all what I would need on it

```
props.routingStore.history.push({pathname :fullUrl,  state: { detail: props.item.id}});
```

I then would do

```
 console.log(this.props.location.state, 'state')
```

I have @withRouter on my components.

Edit

```
history: {length: 35, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}

location:
hash: ""
key: "r7jyux"
pathname: "/members/18/results"
search: ""
state: undefined
__proto__: Object


match:
isExact: true
params: {category: "18"}
path: "/members/:category/results"
url: "/members/18/results"
```

Comment: Please use `console.log(this.props)` and show us

Comment: @kinduser what do you want to see in the props. It's quite big

Comment: I want to check if there's location/match/history props

Comment: @kinduser - ok updated. I am not seeing the previous url. The url that I am printing out is the the url that I "browsed" backed to not.

Comment: I just wonder what would happen if you would just `this.props.history.push({ ... })` without that `routingStore`

Comment: Same result. When I push the page I am going on Mount I check and I see the "state" when I use the back button I just see the previous page Location info and no "state"

Comment: This is pretty weird...

Comment: have you tried removing routingStore and just this.props.history.push

Comment: I tried this.props.history.push and same thing.